# Per-Monitor DPI-aware Win32 application: Resources are still scaled

Tags: visual-c++, dpi

I am currently trying to make my "system dpi aware" WTL application per-monitor dpi aware. Normally this wouldn't be a problem at all - everything works fine, I get the `WM_DPICHANGED` message without any extra flu. The only thing that behaves oddly is, after a reboot past changing the DPI on the main monitor, the Windows resource manager:

Dialogs created without the resource manager *remain unscaled* as expected. All dialogs created with the help of the resource manager are *scaled by Windows 8.1/10*.

-> Code example would be too long, just use the Win32 project template from Visual Studio and set `<dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware>` in the manifest file.

Has anybody experienced the same problem and found a solution for this?

Comment: After spending a fair amount of time with content provided by Kenny Kerr, everything seems to work properly.  The best is his pluralsight content, but hopefully this article will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574798.aspx

Comment: I'll be looking into his pluralsight content, thanks! So far, the article doesn't cover my problem (resource-based dialogs) at all, and the example program he gave still has the problem, that the client area has two different scaling factors for x and y axis, as the window border isn't scaled with the rest of the window. (This one, I could fix...)